# Probabilistic Number Theory

Tags: analytic-number-theory, probabilistic-method

In Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory, he defines Expectation of an arithmetic function $f(n)$ with respect to uniform distribution $v_N$ by

$\mathbb{E_N}(f) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z \;d\mathbb{F_N}(z) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n\leq N} f(n)$

Here, $\mathbb{F_N}(z) = \frac{1}{N} \# \{n \leq N: f(n) \leq z\}$

How do you get the expression with summation from the expression with integral in the definition?

Comment: Searching "Stieltjes integral" will help.

Comment: @SungjinKim I tried that but could not prove it. After applying the Stieltjes integral, the first expression would become $z\mathbb{F_N}(z)\Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, which diverges, right?$

Comment: Yes, there is a problem at $+\infty$. But for every fixed $N$, you can pick finite limits for the integral (or just a finite upper limit; since $F_N(z) = 0$ for all small enough $z$ there's no real problem at $-\infty$). $dF_N(z) = 0$ for large enough $z$, so $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} z\,dF_N(z) = \int_{-M}^{M} z\,dF_N(z)$$ whenever $M \geqslant \max \{ \lvert f(n)\rvert : n \leqslant N\}$.